# How to run container and execute python on docker in one command?

Tags: python, docker, containers

We have a very small python code which we need to run on container.  Following two commands are working fine ,
I want to merge them in one ? the ultimate goal is container should be up(base on image)  , run python and exit by itself.

```
docker run --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/ -t -d pythonimage:latest
docker exec -it mycontainer python3 /usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py
```

I tried -c "/bin/bash python3 /usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py"  this didnt work , it just.

Comment: you can add it in the docker file using`CMD`

Comment: `docker run` takes an optional COMMAND argument to run instead of the specified CMD in the Dockerfile. Would this do what you want? `docker run --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/ -t -d pythonimage:latest python3 /usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py`

Comment: @DHudson the path "/usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py" will be dynamic means everytime I run python on container I will provide different path.

Comment: @deadshot how that CMD works in docker file, can It take dynamic inputs

Comment: use environment variables

Comment: Would docker-compose help you out here?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file called `Dockerfile` (with no dot before or after file name, exactly this one) with the below contents:

```
from ubuntu:20.04
env run=/usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py
cmd ["/bin/bash", "-c", "${run}"]
```

Then run:

```
docker build YOUR_IMAGE_NAME # this should be a new name, like pythonimage2
```

Now run it:

```
docker run --name mycontainer -v /opt/testuser/pythoncode/:/usr/src/app/ -t -d pythonimage2:latest
```

So, now the docker executing command which makes container running is now `/usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py`.

Regarding your answer, you can add a variable and each time just modify that line.

Even you can do this to your `Dockerfile`:

```
from ubuntu:20.04
env path=/usr/src/app/subfolder/
env file=$path/createfile.py
cmd ["/bin/bash", "-c", "${file}"]
```

Now you just need to modify `file` variable. If any of your sub-directories changes, you can remove that from `path` variable and add it to `file` variable.

Comment: I did initially same thing, the problem is hard coded code file  " CMD ["python3", "/usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py"] in my case this path and python file will be change every time.

Comment: Do you mean the path changes every time? Or the contents of your file?

Comment: The path will change every time I start container.  this parameter " /usr/src/app/subfolder/createfile.py" need to be set dynamically .

Comment: OK, so is that good to write a variable? I've edited my answer to add a variable. Check it again and let me know if it resolves your issue.